# SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email: INSERT INTO "users"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I just installed the devise gem and I'm getting the following error:

```
Error:
AccountsControllerTest#test_should_update_account:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE  constraint failed: users.email: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2017-09-19 08:32:47.975048', '2017-09-19 08:32:47.975048', 298486374)
```

This is the procedure I followed:

```
gem 'devise'
bundle install
rails generate devise:install
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
rails generate devise user
devise_for :users, path: 'users'
config.scoped_views = true
rails g devise:views users
rails generate devise:controllers users
```

Any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution! I had to change the `test/fixtures/users.yml` file to this:

```
one:
  email: test1@test.com

two:
  email: test2@test.com
```